Skript works about 95%; 1st Echo ignored, Loading screen cannot be implemented
What I'm trying to accomplish is that the batch file will execute the commands that someone usually types in individually (that takes time), so I wanted to make it into one seamless process with check-points and stuff...
I can get some things work but not all of it, it skips where it shouldnt and doesnt skip where it should.
I used different methods, like Errorlevel, and variables, but that made it worse, the one that I've submitted here is the "most functional" of the all the versions I had:
@ECHO OFF
TITLE YEY-Computer-Checker

START /b /wait cmd.exe /c chkdsk /f/r /y

ECHO The program will continue dont worry! This will only be showed once!
timeout /t 5 nobreak
cls

START /b /wait cmd.exe /c sfc /scannow
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
cls

START /b cmd.exe /c DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
cls

START /b /wait cmd.exe /c DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
cls

IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 START /b /wait cmd.exe /c DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
cls

:end ECHO The YEY-Computer-Checker has finished! Your System seems to be alright! The Programm will close in 5s or press Enter to close immediately.

:Error ECHO The Programm has encountered an Error! And will close automatically in 5s.
timeout /t 5

EXIT

THIS IS THE UPDATED VERSION! So to speak Version 1.1 (95% functional, First echo being ignored, missing pseudo loading bar)
@ECHO OFF

TITLE YEY-Computer-Checker

chkdsk /f/r /y

ECHO The program will continue dont worry! This will only be showed once!

timeout /t 10 nobreak >nul

cls

sfc /scannow

timeout /t 10 /nobreak >nul

cls

DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth

timeout /t 10 /nobreak >nul

cls

DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth

cls

IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

timeout /t 10 /nobreak >nul

cls

ECHO Do you wish to do a [Q]uick Scan a [F]ull Scan or [N]either of the two?
ECHO\
ECHO A Quick Scan will take approx. 10 mins.
ECHO\
ECHO A Full Scan will take longer, approx. 60 mins.

:again

set /p choice=

IF %choice%==Q (

    "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe" -Scan -ScanType 1

)


IF %choice%==F (

    "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe" -Scan -ScanType 2
)


IF %choice%==N ECHO Ok, remember to do a scan manually just in case!

IF NOT %choice%==Q IF NOT %choice%==F IF NOT %choice%==N ECHO Please type the exact letter as shown (without the square brackets) and press Enter! & GOTO again

timeout /t 10 >nul

cls

ECHO The YEY-Computer-Checker has finished! Your System seems to be alright!
ECHO\
ECHO The Programm will automatically close in 10s or press Enter to close immediately.

timeout /t 10

EXIT

THIS IS THE PSEUDO LOADING BAR!
FYI This loading bar is connected to the Windows Defender Process (hopefully)
@ECHO OFF

SET program=MpCmdRun.exe

TASKLIST |FIND /i "%program%" >nul

:loading

IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    
    ECHO Windows Defender is currently scanning!
    ECHO [============]
    TIMEOUT /t 1 >nul
    cls
    ECHO Windows Defender is currently scanning!
    ECHO [========================]
    TIMEOUT /t 1 >nul
    cls
    ECHO Windows Defender is currently scanning!
    ECHO [====================================]
    TIMEOUT /t 1 >nul
    cls
    ECHO Windows Defender is currently scanning!
    ECHO [================================================]
    TIMEOUT /t 1 >nul
    cls
    ECHO Windows Defender is currently scanning!
    ECHO [============================================================]
    TIMEOUT /t 1 >nul
    cls
    IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 EXIT
    GOTO loading
)


Why are you using START or cmd.exe at all?  When you START cmd.exe like that, the ERRORLEVEL you get back is based upon the success or failure of cmd.exe, not of whichever utility you are running inside it, (chkdsk.exe, sfc.exe, or DISM.exe).

In START /b /wait cmd.exe /c chkdsk /f/r /y  line the START command is used to execute cmd.exe in parallel (concurrently), but the /wait  option specify to wait for cmd.exe to terminate. Conclusion: you get the same is you omit START /b /wait part. The cmd /c  command is used to execute the line after it, so you can omit it anyway. Bottom line: you should use a simple chkdsk /f/r /y line instead. The same point apply in all the cases...  You also must remove the  timeout  command before IF NOT ERRORLEVEL  in order to test the value of DISM  command and not timeout...

:end ECHO…  : This structure won't work. Anything following a label eg. :error is ignored. Move the echo command to the next line. Batch simply executes lines serially until a goto or call command is encountered. Reaching :end will show the echo that has been moved & proceed to the echo following :error. In order to reach :error, you need to execute goto error. You would then need to execute either an exit command or goto :eof (here, the colon is required). exit will close the window, so you won't see the message. goto :eof` will simply jump to the End Of File.

Hmm for I changed the code with your suggestions, it seems to at least work in a more predictive way, however it ignores the first ECHO even though theres a timeout. How can i post the current version in here (it seems to be too long). And ill implement a WinDef scan as well so it like works as a multi use scanner (definetely something thats probably useless, sadge, but i have fun creating it and it might help).

I was able to implement the WinDef Scan Option to my script, however now, i cannot implement my pseudo loading screen that i have premade in another batch file. i will send it here, maybe you guys could give me some tipps on how to increase the efficiency and effectiveness of my script.
